# How to use module in my own node js module?

Tags: node.js, module, body-parser

How I can use third party module in my own? For example if I have in app main file something like (using body-parser):

```
app.post("/dothis", (req,res)=>{
    var name = req.body.name;
    console.log(name);
};
```

This work fine. But when I want to have this in separate file (for example mod.js), and wrote like this:

```
exports.own = function(){
       var name = req.body.name;
       console.log(name);
}
```

Then in main file wrote:

```
const mod = require(__dirname + "/mod.js")



app.post("/dothis", (req,res)=>{
        mod.own();
    };
```

Then I get error like, req is undefined.

I am trying to add in mod.js file

```
const {req} = require ("http");
```

So then I got error that can't read value of name undefined.

There is the question, how i can transfer my code which is using body-parser, express and other modules to separate file or creating own module to get working module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because you are not passing the request.

Looking at your code, try this.

```
exports.own = function(req){ // use request
       var name = req.body.name;
       console.log(name);
}

const mod = require(__dirname + "/mod.js")



app.post("/dothis", (req,res)=>{
        mod.own(req); // pass request
    };
```